Troubleshooting Fetching API in React Native: Error Handling and Connectivity Issues
this code has an error because basically the api for the have so many products, but unfortanely only 1 product that can search which is the spark plug, our instructor said that the access token the we are using is static only thats why it can only search 1 product, our instructor said is that make the access token DYANAMIC or make it in global state
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);
  const accessToken = '880|WY9ZQF2qEAxcp1mORAN4lMXRDGDK034mtOVXwPUXc24f7ff9'; // Updated access token
  const shopId = 1; // Updated shop ID

  const searchProduct = async () => {
    try {
      if (!searchTerm.trim()) {
        throw new Error('Please enter a valid search term');
      }

      const apiEndpoint = `https://rackpos.rackappsolutions.com/api/products/search/${shopId}?query=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`;

      const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
        const data = await response.json();

        if (!data || !data.name) {
          throw new Error('Product not found');
        }

        // Check if the fetched product matches the search term
        if (data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
          setProduct(data);
          console.log('Product found:', data);
          Alert.alert('Success', 'Product found!');
        } else {
          throw new Error('Product not found');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error('Response was not in JSON format');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error searching product:', error.message);
      let errorMessage = 'An error occurred while searching for the product. Please try again later.';
      if (error.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
        errorMessage = 'Failed to connect to the server. Please check your internet connection.';
      } else if (error.message === 'Product not found') {
        errorMessage = 'The product you are searching for was not found.';
      }
      console.error('Error:', errorMessage);
      Alert.alert('Error', errorMessage);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Product Search</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={searchTerm}
        onChangeText={setSearchTerm}
        placeholder="Enter product name"
      />
      <Button title="Search" onPress={searchProduct} />
      {product && (
        <View style={styles.productContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.productName}>{product.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.productInfo}>Unit Price: {product.unitPrice}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  productContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  productName: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  productInfo: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default App;

Actually I dont have any idea about this so can someone help me?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read tag descriptions before using them. Both [tag:api] and [tag:fetch] start with "DO NOT USE". Do take the [tour] and read up on [ask].
